# SQL query in python - select rows containing argument from first n rows

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, select, limit

I have a test table with 2000 rows and I am trying to select only from the first 1000 rows those rows where xxx = 0.

I tried with:

```
mydb.cursor().execute("SELECT column_N FROM test_table LIMIT 1000 WHERE xxx = 0")
```

but this returns an error.

Note: I wish to get the rows containing the argument from within the first 1000 rows and not the first 1000 rows containing the argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHERE clause needs to be placed before LIMIT:

```
SELECT column_N 
FROM test_table 
WHERE xxx = 0
-- ORDER BY col_name  -- to have stable resultset, ORDER BY is needed
LIMIT 1000
```

---

EDIT:

```
SELECT s.column_N
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM test_table 
    ORDER BY col_name  -- to have stable first 1000 rows, ORDER BY is needed
    LIMIT 1000) s
WHERE s.xxx = 0;
```

Tables are unordered sets, so `LIMIT 1000` may vary betweens runs, that is why `ORDER BY` was added.

Comment: Hi Lukasz, thanks, but this is the opposite to what I need. I tried it and it returns the first 1000 rows containing the argument. I need it vice versa - the rows containing the argument from within the first 1000 table rows.